# Epson EcoTank printer on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, printing, scanner, epson

I am considering buying an **EcoTank Epson** printer (f.x. ET-4550). However it would not be smart to use the money just to find out later that it does not work in Ubuntu. Therefore, I hope there is somebody who has tried EcoTank printer line (ET-4550, ET-2500, e.t.c.) in Ubuntu 16. I would like to hear about your experience:

1. Does the **printer** work through the **local network** (ethernet or wifi), not USB?
2. Does the printer offer a web-interface from which **scanning** is possible from the browser, through the **local network**, so that the scanned pdf (or image) can be downloaded to the local PC? If not, does the the scanning work and how (not via USB)?

(knowing that finding hardware compatible with linux is not an easy task I hope that providing specific model names in such messages will help others too)

Thank you

Comment: These printers are fully supported. You can get linux drivers here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Answer (score 6):

I  bought a **L6190**.

I installed the drivers on this [page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

I also installed the packages:

`printer-driver-escpr`, `lsb` (Linux Standard Base support package)

I have ubuntu 16.04

Printing over wifi works great.

This was a helpful link:

- https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/03/15/driver-epson-l6190-ubuntu-18-04-how-to-download-install/
- http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/imagescanv3_e.html#sec6-4-3

After some editing of config file (described in manual of imagescan), I got scanning to work over wifi as well. Its great!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Installing `printer-driver-escpr` alone helped in my case (ubuntu 20.04, focal fossy).

Comment: @bohdan_trotsenko Can you elaborate a bit further on your answer? I'm sure you meant #sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr, which I've run.
But then what? The printer just magically showed when selecting "Print" off a document?
Or what software did you use?

Comment: @CRutherford if I remember well, prior to installing this package my system did see a printer as I tried to add it; afterwards, running "add printer" dialog found one.